# How to export all functions from typescript file with default?

Tags: typescript

Common example of this export type is React. We can use this: `import React, {Component} from "react"`. And then we can use both React.Component and Component. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure you have module `CommonJS` in `tsconfig.json`
2. wrap all functions in module and add export keyword to all you want to export
3. Add `export = <YOUR MODULE NAME>` to the end of your file